libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Tramsform
Programs created by Lazarus don't launch on Ubuntu 24.04. It works fine on older distributions. The error message is
symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gpu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Transform
It looks it is something to do with libfreetype. I have installed libfreetype through official repository. Any help?

The symbol appears to be present for me (as confirmed by nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.20.1 | grep FT_Get_Transform for example)

libharfbuzz.so.0 doesn't have that function. It is "U".

So are you creating programs with Lazarus on Ubuntu 24.04, or are you trying to run a program that was created on a different (perhaps older) system?

The program is created on 20.04. I had to install libharfbuzz0b, libpango1, libpangoft2, libcairo2 from 22.04 to make it running in 24.04.
